# Sequential scan with large sub-query filter "never" ends

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-performance

I'm using postgres 9.2.4, and run the following query:

```
explain analyze select * from bubu where id not in
     (select bubu_id from kuku limit 33554431);
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on bubu  (cost=913175.15..1041265.77 rows=1761465 width=160) (actual time=37565.575..42569.266 rows=596 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 3511745
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..829289.07 rows=33554431 width=8) (actual time=20.528..22363.943 rows=33554431 loops=1)
           ->  Seq Scan on kuku  (cost=0.00..830246.84 rows=33593184 width=8) (actual time=20.528..18741.263 rows=33554431 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 42579.485 ms
(7 rows)
```

And then the second query, which never ends:

```
explain analyze select * from bubu where id not in
   (select bubu_id from kuku limit 33554433)
```

The query without limit also gets stuck

```
explain analyze select * from bubu where id not in
   (select bubu_id from kuku)
```

Explain of the stuck query:

```
explain select * from bubu where id not in
   (select bubu_id from kuku) 

                                  QUERY PLAN                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on bubu  (cost=0.00..2137396495180.43 rows=1761465 width=160)
   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1129436.76 rows=33593184 width=8)
           ->  Seq Scan on kuku  (cost=0.00..830246.84 rows=33593184 width=8)
   (5 rows)
```

The query I actually need is

```
delete from bubu where id not in
     (select bubu_id from kuku)
```

Is there any PostgreSQL parameter I can tune to avoid this issue?

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the query to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`? Is there an index on `kuku (bubu_id)`?

Comment: @stickybit , there is an index. NOT EXISTS indeed helps in this case!

Answer (score 2):

Your queries are slow because they in fact do a lot. In your

```
explain analyze
    select * from bubu where id not in
    (select bubu_id from kuku limit 33554431);
```

example, the database is fetching up to 33,554,431 rows in undefined order from `kuku`, doing another scan on `bubu` to select rows that are not among the fetched 33m+ rows, and then finally fetching and returning rows that fit such a condition.

If you wanna do

```
delete from bubu where id not in
(select bubu_id from kuku)
```

then your options are:

1. Just run it and wait.
2. Do it in chunks:

   1. Fetch all the IDs that you are going to compare against into a separate table:

      ```
      CREATE TABLE temp_bubu_ids AS SELECT bubu_id FROM kuku;
      ```
   2. Fetch 1000 or so IDs from the IDs table, delete them and then delete rows from `bubu` that match your condition:

      ```
      WITH deleted_ids AS (
          DELETE FROM temp_bubu_ids

          -- DELETE doesn't support LIMIT
          WHERE ctid IN (
              SELECT ctid
              FROM temp_bubu_ids
              LIMIT 1000
          )
          RETURNING id
      )
      DELETE FROM bubu
      WHERE id NOT IN (
          SELECT id
          FROM deleted_ids
      )
      ```
   3. Rinse and repeat until all the appropriate rows get deleted.

Comment: Another option is to create new_table as select bubu_id from kuku limit 33554431, then index bubu_id on new_table, then put new_table in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it qualifies as an answer...

My question was asked here (failed to come up with the "Materialized" keyword) and got the answer I looked for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477353/postgres-materialize-causes-poor-performance-in-delete-query